# Regex to turn a list of strings into numbers following a specific rule

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a list in the form;

```
lst = ["5kxn"] # 1 string only for example
```

5k denotes 5000 and xn denotes n times, the processed list should be;

```
[5*1e3 for i in range(n)] # float values
#Not this literally but a list of n 5000's.
```

I am aware I can do this using non re methods but it could be bug prone, and my re skills are not good enough to come up with a method to pull off this conversion

Here is a dictionary of multipliers:

```
replace_dict = {'a': '1e-18', 'f': '1e-15', 'p': '1e-12',
                'n': '1e-9',  'u': '1e-6',  'm': '1e-3',
                'c': '1e-2',  'd': '1e-1', 'da': '1e1',
                'h': '1e2',   'k': '1e3',   'M': '1e6',
                'G': '1e9',   'T': '1e12',  "P": '1e15',
                'E': '1e18'}
```

Desired output is a list. For example `["2kx1","3kx2","4k"]` will be `[2000.0,3000.0,3000.0,4000.0]`

Comment: Your current question is misleading, but it makes it sound like you want to take a string input `5kxn` and then generate a single output list (via a comprehension).  It appears that you want to input a list of multiple strings.  Please _edit_ your question and reveal the real problem.

Comment: I clearly said a list, I don't know why you keep on insisting that my question is misworded when you misinterpreted it, I even clarified that for you. Its obvious that if its a list, regardless of the #elements the function will work.

Comment: Each element of that input list appears to generate an output list.  So, is your desired output a list of lists?  Something else?  Can you answer any of my questions here?

Comment: Desired output is a list. For example ["2kx1","3kx2","4k"] will be [2000,3000,3000,4000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

replace_dict = {'a': '1e-18', 'f': '1e-15', 'p': '1e-12',
                'n': '1e-9',  'u': '1e-6',  'm': '1e-3',
                'c': '1e-2',  'd': '1e-1', 'da': '1e1',
                'h': '1e2',   'k': '1e3',   'M': '1e6',
                'G': '1e9',   'T': '1e12',  "P": '1e15',
                'E': '1e18'}

def str_to_list(list_str):
    regex = re.compile(r"([0-9]+)([^x]+)(x[0-9]+)?")
    list_numbers = []
    for string in list_str:
        parsed = re.findall(regex, string)[0]
        n = 1 if parsed[2] == '' else int(parsed[2].replace('x', ''))
        list_numbers += [float(parsed[0]) * eval(replace_dict[parsed[1]])] * n 
    return list_numbers

result = str_to_list(["2kx1","3kx2","4k"])
print(result)  # [2000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0]
```

A bit of explanation:

- `([0-9]+)`: captures what comes before the unit prefix, e.g. `k`.
- `([^x]+)`: captures the unit prefix (anything that is not an "x"). This could be refined so it only accepts the letters defined in `replace_dict`. The `+` is needed because of the 'da' prefix.
- `(x[0-9]+)?`: captures the multiplier, e.g. `x2`, if exists.

The method `re.findall` returns a list, in these case containing a tuple with the groups captured by the regex, e.g.: `[('22', 'k', 'x2')]` for "22kx2". We take `[0]` to work directly with the tuple.

If the "xn" is missing, `re.findall` will return an empty string for the group `(x[0-9]+)?` since there's not any match, e.g.: `[('2', 'k', '')]` for "2k". That's why `n` is `1` if that string is empty, else we discard the `x` (replacing it with an empty string, i.e. `replace('x', '')`), so we only take the number, e.g. `2` in "x2".

Finally, we concatenate the resulting list to `list_numbers`, e.g. `list_numbers += [2 * eval("1e3")] * 2` in case of "2kx2".

Hope that was clear enough :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex based approach which ultimately uses the `eval()` function to evaluate a string expression to generate a list:

```py
def get_list(inp):
    replace_dict = {'a': '1e-18', 'f': '1e-15', 'p': '1e-12',
                    'n': '1e-9',  'u': '1e-6',  'm': '1e-3',
                    'c': '1e-2',  'd': '1e-1', 'da': '1e1',
                    'h': '1e2',   'k': '1e3',   'M': '1e6',
                    'G': '1e9',   'T': '1e12',  'P': '1e15',
                    'E': '1e18'}
    parts = re.findall(r'^(\d+)(\w+)x(\w+)$', inp)
    expr = "[" + parts[0][0] + "*" + replace_dict[parts[0][1]] + " for i in range(" + parts[0][2] + ")]"
    return expr

expr = get_list("5kxn")
print(expr)  # [5*1e3 for i in range(n)]
n = 5
lst = eval(expr)
print(lst)   # [5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0]
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, the function should accept a list, and if I just input "5k" there's an error, "5k" should return a list of [5000]

Comment: That's not what your question appears to be asking.  Please edit your question with the actual problem in this case.

Comment: I mentioned that the function should accept a list in the first line of my question.

Comment: I don't even see the point of passing in a list, given that it just contains a single string inside it.  The _output_ is the critical thing here; you expect a list defined by the comprehension you gave in the question above, and my answer does this.

Comment: Because I ultimately want to pass a list with more than one element and getting the new list as per the question,  I can do that using your answer, but that would be a messy implementation.